# Using a priority_queue of int with custom compare

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue

I have numbers from `1` to `n`, and an array of priorities `P` of size `n`.
I want to declare a priority queue using `P` as their priorities.

I don't want to define a new type of object that contains the number and its priority, I want to use a priority queue of int objects and pass a custom comparison object that depends on `P` to `std::priority_queue`. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

`std::priority_queue<int, vector<int>, [P](int i, int j){ return P[i]<P[j]; }> PQ;`

I also tried defining a class with a `bool operator(int i, int j) {P[i] < P[j]}` member and a constructor where I can pass `P` to it but that also didn't work.

How should I declare my priority queue?

---

The following seems to work:

```
class MyLess{
 public:
  MyLess(const int* p) {p_ = p;}
  bool operator()(const int &lhs, const int &rhs) const { return p_[lhs] < p_[rhs]; }

 private:
  const int* p_;
};
...
std::priority_queue<int, vector<int>, MyLess> PQ(P);
```

Comment: How exactly did not it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option #1

```
#include <functional>
// ...
std::priority_queue<int
                  , std::vector<int>
                  , std::function<bool(int,int)>
                  >
                  PQ([P] (int i, int j) { return P[i] < P[j]; });
```

#### Option #2

```
auto cmp = [P] (int i, int j) { return P[i] < P[j]; };

std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> PQ(cmp);
```

Comment: The first one gives the following error similar to what I was getting:
"no matching function for call to 'std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(int, int)> >::priority_queue(methodname::__lambda0)'
PQ([T] (int i, int j) { return T[i] < T[j]; });"

Comment: @Kaveh and the compiler you use is... ?

Comment: gcc-4.8.1. The second one causes internal compiler error (gcc-4.8.1): 0x4ea72c check_initializer
../../../work/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/cp/decl.c:5590
0x4edab2 cp_finish_decl(tree_node*, tree_node*, bool, tree_node*, int)
../../../work/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/cp/decl.c:6347
...

Comment: @Kaveh [demo1](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vh3oBzzKTfPM9DR0), [demo2](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/s1cxdthOEjfrnQSQ)